# Outlook and system beeps

Tags: windows-xp, audio, microsoft-outlook-2003

Whenever i receive an email through outlook my computer makes a beep noise, is there anyway to turn this off
I have disabled all sounds on the machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to **Tools** --> **Options** --> **Email Options** --> **Advanced Email Options** and then uncheck the box that says **Play a Sound**

Answer (score 2):

Re-enable all system beeps, then in Outlook,
go to Tools -> Options -> Preferences Tab -> Email Options button -> Advanced Email Options,
and uncheck 'Play a sound' where it says 'When new items arrive in my inbox '.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing it. Check out [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/turn-off-the-annoying-windows-xp-system-beeps/) for a walkthrough.

1. **Disable the beep driver in device manager.**
   Go to device manager
   Hit View->Show hidden devices
   Find "Beep" under "Non plug and play drivers"
   Right click and goto properties
   On the "Driver" tab change the startup type to "Disabled"
2. **Disable the beep in the registry.**
   Set HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Sound\Beep to "no"
3. **Disable the beep in the sounds control panel app.**
   In the sounds control panel app, on the sounds tab
   Find the "Default Beep" sound and set it to "none"

I've found that disabling the driver in device manager is the most system wide effective way.